# why my udid in app is different udid in organizer?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, udid

Why my udid in app is different udid in organizer? Why idid in app is change when rebuilding app in Xcode? My udid in organiser is 2be84094607d6b730eb9fffc6e5b... but in app is 683F8A15-DF8B-425A-9BCE ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since iOS7 you can no longer access the device UDID. What you see is a vendor UDID, this means that is different for each version, and changes when the device is reset or when the app is reinstalled.